# Email Attachment File Path

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I am using Drupal 7 with the [WebForm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and [MIME Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) modules.

I've got webform attachments being sent in the email working fine. However the email also contains a path to view the email in a directory on the server. Currently, it's set to `/sites/default/files/webform/sites/default/files/webform/ /`.

How can I change the directory where WebForm submissions are stored?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know they've got to stay within /sites/default/files/webform/ folder as /sites/default/files is the only folder that should be both writable and publically accessible

If you edit the file component you added to your webform you can then specify a folder within /sites/default/files/webform/ that you'd like them to be stored specifically for that form. Look for the "upload directory" field.